# Python How do i add/remove items in a RPG Inventory system

Tags: python

I know how to make a simple inventory, but how do I add and remove items?
Here is my inventory:`inventory = ["Sword", "Shield", "Helmet", "Gloves"]`
I can print the inventory: `print inventory`
I use Python 2.7.10
I tried this but doesn't work: `inventory.add("Gun")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an item to an array use : `inventory.append("item")`

To remove an item from an array use : `inventory.remove("item")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()` to append to a list

Answer (score 0):

"inventory" is a list

The function for adding an item to a list is "append"

```
inventory.append("Gun")
```

would do what you want.